# Would it be possible to get Terraria Collector’s Edition working on Ubuntu? If so, how? Wine for CDs? General compatibility?

Tags: 14.10, games

Would it be possible to get Terraria Collector's Edition working on Ubuntu 14.10? If so, how? Wine for CDs? General compatibility?

I was wondering about getting my friend, (who has no internet access, so I have to do all this for him) a copy of Terraria Collector's Edition. I do not use Ubuntu, but I need to ask questions for him here.

How would I get it working on his computer? He's got Ubuntu 14.10.

Is it already generally compatible? Or does it require the use of some form of Wine (the multi-platform program runner, of course) for CDs, or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Terraria. Not specifically the collector's edition (but if that is a collection of several Terraria games)...

- [Here](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/wip-monogame-terraria-terraria-for-linux.72997/) is a how to on installing Terraria and using it *directly* in Ubuntu. Basic instructions (kudos to Deathmax):

  **Installation Instructions**

  1. Grab the Content folder and Terraria.exe from Steam. (Either via wine or a Windows install)
  2. Check the exe hashes at the bottom Extract the downloaded binaries archive  somewhere.
  3. Run bspatch to patch Terraria.exe with the .patch file included in the archive.
  4. Run mono Terraria.exe

  Music Instructions

  1. Make sure you have ffmpeg, python and perl installed.
  2. Extract the music conversion archive into the Content folder.
  3. Run perl xactxtract2.pl -x "Wave Bank.xwb"
  4. Run convertmusic.sh
  5. Run python MakeXwb.py "Wave Bank.xwb"
  6. Make sure the file list outputted is in order.

  Music should now work. (albeit with a 80MB Wave Bank with uncompressed PCM data)

[image]

---

When using WINE ...

- Use WINE 1.7.8 and disable gameoverlayrenderer. You will see this mentioned on the [wineHQ apps](https://www.winehq.org/search?q=terraria) site and also that almost all versions of Terraria have a "yes it runs" with a gold rating.
- You can find a [Play on Linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1576-Terraria.html) script here if you want to do it yourself.
- Here is a how to for [Play on Linux](http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/i-finally-found-a-way-to-run-terraria-on-ubuntu-playonlinux.5477/) (kudos to MadbriX|CVG):

  1. Open Up PlayOnLinux and install your "Terraria.exe" with it. Click the button with the plus sign and says "Install" and a window should open up. In the
     lower left-hand side corner, there should be a button that says "Install a non-listed program". Follow the instructions (Be sure to create a "New Virtual Drive" when it asks). Navigate to where your Terraria.exe was saved to after download and press install. It will take a few minutes, but it's worth it ;)
     When Installation is finished, close the Install window and go back to the original main menu of PlayOnLinux.
  2. Now, in the main menu, click on the Configure Button with the Gear Icon, and the "Configure" Window should open up.
  3. In the Configure window, select "Terraria" in the side panel.
  4. Click on the tab "Install Components". This is where you can see all the needed components for different Video Games.
  5. Scroll down the list of components and at the bottom of the list, you should see "xna40". This is Microsoft XNA 4.0! Your Terraria won't recognize it if it was installed manually from the website for some strange reason.
  6. Select the "xna40" and click Install. Once it has finished, select the tab called "Miscellaneous" can click on the button "Run a .exe file from this virtual drive"
  7. The opening folder should show your recently used "Terraria.exe". Click on it, and wait around a few seconds for the game to initiate.
  8. Enjoy the game! Let me know in the comments if there are any errors encountered.